# User image and name is not getting from roaster -XMPP iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I am trying to develop an XMPP chat application for iPhone. This is my first XMPP application, so i have only some basic idea about the the framework. 
In my application I have a UICollectionView in my home page(I need to display the users listing on a horizontal scroll, so I am using UICollectionView), where I am loading the last chatted users from the XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject entity. But on that entity there is no user image and name, so I am trying to access it from the XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject entity using the jidStr.

But at the first time of loading the application, I didn't get the images and names of the users (getting it as null). But when I got a message new message from any of the user, then all the images and names are loading.

Any idea about this issue ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

xmpp take 2-3 seconds to connect to server and goes online. before user connect to server your collection view is loaded in VC. you just need to refresh your collection view when you got presence in

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence

when you got you present that you are online just refresh that collectionview